# Creating a New Class with Collection Initializers in C#

Tags: c#, collections, collection-initializer

I have a class that I created. I would like to allow the class to be able to have a collection initializer. Here is an example of the class:

```
public class Cat
{
    private Dictionary catNameAndType = new Dictionary();

    public Cat()
    {

    }

    public void Add(string catName, string catType)
    {
        catNameAndType.Add(catName,catType);
    }

}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this with the class:

```
Cat cat = new Cat()
{
    {"Paul","Black"},
    {"Simon,"Red"}
}
```

Is this possible to do with classes that are not Dictionaries and Lists?

Answer (score 12):

In addition to an `Add` method, the class must also implement the `IEnumerable` interface.

See also: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Actually, you almost solved it yourself. The requirements to use a collection initializer like that, is an `Add` method that takes two methods (which you have), and that the type implements IEnumerable (which you are missing). So to get your code to work; use something like:

```
public class Cat : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
{
    private Dictionary<string,string> catNameAndType = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    public Cat()
    {

    }

    public void Add(string catName, string catType)
    {
        catNameAndType.Add(catName,catType);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string,string>> GetEnumerator() 
    {
        return catNameAndType.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() 
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh... Looks like we were both writing ours at same time...

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as stated in other answers (just to give more detail), just implement `IEnumerable<T>` and have some `Add()` method(s):

```
// inherit from IEnumerable<whatever>
public class Cat : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> catNameAndType = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Cat()
    {

    }

    // have your Add() method(s)
    public void Add(string catName, string catType)
    {
        catNameAndType.Add(catName, catType);
    }

    // generally just return an enumerator to your collection
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return catNameAndType.GetEnumerator();
    }

    // the non-generic form just calls the generic form
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```